# Unable to apply my model on separate test file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

This is the training model and `df` is the dataframe:
Then, I've applied some operations according to the requirement:

```
vocab_size = 10000
tokenize = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)

tokenize.fit_on_texts(df.review_description)
print(len(tokenize.word_index) + 1)

X = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(df.review_description, mode='tfidf')

encoder = LabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit(df.variety)
Y = encoder.transform(df.variety)

del df

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
print(x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

del X
del Y
```

Here is the model operation:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=x_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],
              optimizer='adam')

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=5)

model_output = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
             batch_size=32,
             epochs=100,
             verbose=2,
             callbacks=[es],
             validation_split=0.2)
print('Training Accuracy : ' , np.mean(model_output.history["accuracy"]))
print('Validation Accuracy : ' , np.mean(model_output.history["val_accuracy"]))
```

Everything is working correctly, just the problem is that I'm doing this on all the train data.
How to apply this on the another "test.csv" file?

Comment: On test.csv, apply the same transformation operations as were applied to obtain x_train, y_train, x_test and y_test before they were split and try to apply model.predict() to it.

Comment: I pre-process the data and then apply the model but then also, problem is that when I predict, I get the output in numbers, and this is a classifier wine problem, how to print the result in name @AdhiraDeogade

Comment: I think, you will need to map your output (numbers) in a format you desire, however, in order to obtain accuracy you will only need to compare the test and train outputs, irrespective of its format (numbers, or class names or anything else.